# How to fill in holes on randomly generated maze?

Tags: javascript

One major problem that I have with building a randomly generated maze structure is that often times there will be holes in an already concealed area. For a very basic example, this randomly generated "maze" (not really but just a very basic example) can sometimes form these hollow spots. 1 means there is a wall and 0 is no wall.

```
    let grid = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ];
    for (let count = 0; count < grid.length; count++) {
        for (let coun = 0; coun < grid.length; coun++) {
            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                grid[count][coun] = 1
            }
        }
    }
```

One result I've gotten before from this is:

```
0: (6) [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
1: (6) [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
2: (6) [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
3: (6) [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
4: (6) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

A perfect example of one of these hollow spots is in there. On rows 1, 2, and 3, a structure that has a hollow inside can be found:

```
1: (6) [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
2: (6) [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
3: (6) [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Although this structure also has no bottom left corner, that doesn't really matter. The problem I have is that this hollow spot is not able to be reached by my rules, and I don't really know how to fix this issue for all instances. It can really be any shape. In this case it was just an easy square, but as more and more rows are added, those shapes will become more and more complex. I'm honestly lost on how I'd code a good solution to this that fills in those hollow spots, so that the result can be:

```
0: (6) [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
1: (6) [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
2: (6) [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
3: (6) [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
4: (6) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

where the hollow center now has a wall filled in. Does anyone know a good way to fill in these hollow points?

Comment: A simple change to your algorithm gets rid of holes: 1  means wall on right, 0 means wall on bottom. You can even add 3: no walls.